# How do I specify conditions from 2 different beans in a jsf rendered attribute?

Tags: java, jsf, rendered-attribute

I want to do something along the lines of the following but when I use it like this I get a parse error telling me an entity needs to directly follow the '&' character:

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox
rendered="#{!bean1.condition1 && bean2.condition2}"
value="#{bean1.selected}">
<f:selectItems value="#{bean2.items}" />
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>
```

How can I get rendered to check conditions from 2 different beans?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use 'and' instead:

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox rendered="#{!bean1.condition1 and bean2.condition2}" value="#{bean1.selected}">
```

Comment: Probably should have tried that before asking. Good to know though, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

karim79 is right, you can just use the `and` operator.

In addition to that, you can have a look to this [page](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html), which explains the Expression Language (EL) with several examples...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using facelets which assumes every jsp page after compilation is a xml file. And you know in an xml file you have to provide an xml entity name just after the `&` symbol. So to escape this situation use `&amp;` in place of `&`.